# Comma before "except for?"

Tags: commas, except

I am wondering if there should be a comma before the word "except" in this sentence. The research I have done reveals that commas usually aren't used, but I think that it depends on the sentence. I cannot find a significant explanation as to when commas would be used or not. My instinct is that this situation would be the same as a comma before "because:" add a comma if necessary to avoid confusion. Is the sentence below correct?

**"I have been the judge of hundreds of card tournaments, and I do not have any disciplinary actions on my record, except for two warnings that were given years ago."**

Answer (score 2):

The word *[except](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/except)* in the sentence is a conjunction, therefore a comma is required before *except*, as stipulated in [Comma Usage Rule 3b](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp).

Comment: That would be fine except that there are not two independent clauses here.

Even if it's a separate clause - which looks moot - 'except for two warnings…' is not independent, It's clearly dependent on what went before.

In what ay, precisely, does the comma change the meaning, plase?